# ¿Como recuperar una rama borrada de git?

Tags: git

Acabo de borrar una rama de git.
Por ejemplo :

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
echo "Viva yo" > test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git checkout -b rama
echo "Viva tu" > test2.txt
git add .
git commit -m "test2"
git checkout master
git branch -D rama
```

¿Como puedo recuperar la rama que acabo de borrar?
Si supiese el hash del commit podría recuperarla con :

```
git checkout -b rama EL_HASH
```

Pero no se el hash que tiene, no lo miré.

Comment: Si no la enviaste al repositorio remoto y la has borrado creo que no se puede recuperar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes intentar:

`git fsck --full --no-reflogs | grep commit`

Para encontrar el commit HEAD de la rama borrada.

Si quieres encontrar qué commit es el correcto puedes hacer uso de `git show`

Y una vez tengas el mensaje de commit localizado, crear la rama de nuevo con un `git branch <uid>`

Answer (score 5):

Según tengo entendido puedes utilizar `git reflog` para ver los commit que has ido haciendo y te tiene que aparecer el SHA.

Con eso puedes hacer `git checkout -b <rama> <sha>`

Comment: Esta respuesta me ha sido muy útil en el caso de borrar una rama local sin subir al repo online. Con el reflog y mirando detenidamente puedes encontrar descripciones como "Checkout from branch A to branch B" donde B era la borrada. Así puedes recuperar el commit y re hacer la rama desde ahí.

Answer (score 4):

Algunas veces por cansancio o cualquier otra circunstancia se  borran  ramas o  eliminan archivos y en pro de recuperar lo sin el conocimiento necesario terminamos empeorando la situación y cuando vamos a revisar la rama con el comando `git log` podemos ver que  ya no existe y es cuando entra la desesperación de haber perdido  trabajo valioso.
a mi me paso y  después de jalarme los pelos y buscar encontré una una solución 
que me ayudo a recuperar mi rama.
los pasos son  :

1. Usa el comando `git reflog`  que  permite ver inclusive  lo que ya no esta disponible con `git log`
   Esto sacara un listado como el siguiente de todo lo que ha pasado en git, allí ubicaremos el Head que estaba funcionando bien antes de nuestro problema, es decir al que queremos regresar.

[image: Resultado de comando reflog]

2. Copia el GUID del HEAD que tenia la versión que quieres recuperar (el HEAD es el que está encerrado en rojo en la imagen arriba) este seria en el que aún todo  funcionaba bien.
3. Ahora con el comando `reset`  podremos regresar al estado deseado, borrando **DEFINITIVAMENTE** todo lo que este posterior a ella, tenga cuidado el siguiente comando borra para siempre todo y regresa a un estado previo, así que asegúrese de estar tomando la versión correcta y que el Head que escogió es a donde quiere regresar, para este comando usaremos el identificador único GUID, el que esta en Azul en la siguiente imagen 
   [image: Imagen del Guid a recuperar en color Azul]

escriba el siguiente comando `git reset  --hard    0f71e0d` y presione enter.

4. Revisa que todo debió quedar igual a como estaba cuando todo funcionaba.

Comment: No soy experto en git, pero me da la sensación que la respuesta podría ser correcta. Pero es un poco escueta ¿Podrías añadir detalles de por qué tu propuesta soluciona el problema?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ¿Has probado a hacer lo que se dice en esta respuesta? Yo sí y, en efecto, permite recuperar commits de ramas borradas. Me parece detalle suficiente.

Comment: @JoseAntonioReinstateMonica echa un vistazo al [historial de revisiones de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/307800/revisions), cuando escribí el comentario la respuesta era mucho más escueta.

Answer (score 1):

si has borrado una rama de tu local con  `git branch -d local_branch` y quieres bajarte el contenido de la rama remota, entonces puedes un fetch a la rama remota

```
git fetch origin remote_branch
```

aun no se vera entre tus ramas locales, pero una ves hecho eso puedes moverte

```
git checkout -b local_branch
```

ejemplo:

te debes situar en otra rama, y eliminas tu rama dev de tu local:
`git branch -d dev`

ahora haces fetch del dev remoto `git fetch origin dev`

y ahora te mueves hacia el para que aparesca: `git checkout -b dev`

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso estaba ordenando unos archivos reservados y por error borré uno con el desarrollo. Pensé que había perdido todo el trabajo, pero al buscar en internet, encontré este comando para el git bash

```
gitk --all $( git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' )
```

al ejecutarlo muestra una lista con todo commit stash y cuanta cosa hayan hecho en la rama, exista o no.

[image: all activities]

ahi en la imagen se ve el stash que fue borrado

[image: restore stash option]

Comment: Es más o menos lo mismo que propuso [esta respuesta].(https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103607) Solo que en lugar de `grep` usa `awk` y está pensado para`gitk`.